# AngularJS text input validation with counter

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, counter, ng-maxlength

I'm developing an app containing a form which has a text input with `ng-model="description"`.
Now I want to validate this text input using `ng-maxlength="50"` and `required`. This works fine, but I also want to add a character counter (like `67/50`) shown at all times. I'm using the following code to display the counter: `{{description.length || 0}}/50`

The issue with this, however, is that `description.length` doesn't return a value when it's greater than 50, because `description` input is invalid. In my scenario the counter would default to `0/50` when there's no input (and that's fine) but also when input exceeds max length.

I would also like to display my counter in red when the input length's invalid, but that shouldn't be too hard using angular validation css classes.

Of course I could provide custom validation, but I'm positive there's an easier solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the form element $viewValue instead like this:

```
<form name='form'>

  <input type="text" name='description' ng-model='description' ng-maxlength="50">
  {{form.description.$viewValue.length || 0}}/50
</form>
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oy98xR184TA9XMq2UIeQ?p=info)